# How can I create text underlayed with sprites in Unity UI?

Tags: unity, text-mesh-pro

I have some UI text in a canvas that I'd like to be able to render with sprites behind some of the characters.

This is effect I'd like to achieve:

[image: What I want]

I've been able to use Text Mesh Pro UI text objects with a Sprite Atlas to get most of the way there. I'm using the text tag `<cspace=-1.3em>` to overlay the number `5` and the sprite. But the sprite always renders above the number `5` like this:

[image: What I've got]

Since the Text Mesh Pro Sprite creates a submesh game object underneath the main text game object this makes sense. The canvas UI rendering system renders the Sprite asset second. I've tried moving the submesh game object in the hierarchy, but this is not a good solution because the main text object recreates the submesh object.

I'm looking for a generic solution so that I can programmatically set the text and sprites from a single string. Like how Text Mesh Pro sprite tags (`<cspace=-1.3em>5<sprite name="Shield"></cspace>`) work.

Does anyone know how to achieve this effect?

*Please note that this is a UI component (Rect Transform). Solutions that rely on the non-UI Text Mesh Pro asset will not work for me.*